# display view regarding to authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

When it comes to display a view regarding to authentication (view displayed depending to the visitor if he's a user or not). I face many choices. So I need your help to show me how i deal with such situation :

- Using 2 views (one for the users and other for visitors), or just one view.
- using 2 actions (one with authorize filter and the other without), or just one action.

And why the choices you suggest is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to not use `Authorize` attribute. It's main function is to setup the `User` in the context, and then by default, it also checks that they are logged in. However, this last part can be overridden by using the `AllowAnonymous` attribute as well:

```
[Authorize]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult SomeView()
{
    ...
}
```

So, now your view will have a `User` to play with, and you can dynamically present different pieces of the view using that based on auth status:

```
@if (User.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Logged in</p>
}
else
{
    <p>Anonymous</p>
}
```

**EDIT (for clarification)**

The `Authorize` attribute actually does two distinct things for you. First, it setups all the machinery for recognizing a user: reads the cookie or whatever, checks the authentication status, pulls in the user's info, if they are authenticated, etc. Second, it validates that the user is in fact logged in. Using `AllowAnonymous` skips this second part and allows anyone, logged in or not, to access the view, BUT and this is key, you still need the first part to know stuff like whether you have an authenticated user or not.

So, simply, using both the `Authorize` and `AllowAnonymous` attributes together means essentially, "see if the user is logged in, but don't require it to access this view". That allows anonymous users to still reach the page, but enables you to still deliver unique or different content to an actual logged in user.

Comment: thank you, but why using Authorize then override it with Allowanonymous, i mean why we don't omit the two attributes

Comment: If you don't use `Authorize`, then User will not be populated in the context with the logged in user (if one exists).

Comment: i didn't understund, can you explain one more time please

Comment: from where have you learned this, why the ebooks i read don't tell all this about [Authorize]

Comment: but there is something wrong here, i am using mvc 4, and it works for me even if i don't add any attribute, other thing about User it works this way User.Identity.IsAuthenticated